# Can't debug application on IOS Device

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I created a vanilla PCL project in xamarin forms. I tried to run on Android and it works fine.

But when I change de target to IOS and select my real device (Ipad with IOS 11.4.1), Visual studio only allows me to build solution, I wanna to run application on it but I can't.
The target IOS is 8.0, and I already authenticated with my apple account and created a provisioning profile.

I already done this on another project before and works fine.

I really don't know why Visual Studio don't allow me to debug, when I open my oldest project with this device it allows me to debug.

Comment: Can the project  debug on iPhoneSimulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I was trying to use "Debug", and it works fine on the emulator, but to real device I need to use "Debug | Iphone" or otherwise it only builds.

Even when I try to use "Release" it's the same trick.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running Visual Studio on? IOS requires MAC, whereas Android is compatible with all OS. It's been a while, but I know there's an option to wirelessly connect to a MAC OS so that you can run your IOS Xamarin Forms application anywhere.

Comment: I'm running on mac, with High Sierra 10.13.6
I can run fine by USB another older project, but not the news.

Comment: Great. Is it throwing an error, or simply not allowing you to run the project?

Comment: That is frustrating. Off the top of my head, not sure how to proceed. I will do some research, and hope to get back to you. Keep playing around with the connection between your real device and MAC!

Comment: Can you add your Xamarin Forms version / Visual Studio version?

Comment: Both are the latest. VS 2017: 7.6.1 XM: 3.1.0.69

Comment: Hey, congrats on finding the solution! That is an annoying nuance.